# Send a form parameter with link_to in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a checkout form that has a select field for location which calls a custom action that updates the page via javascript with the correct delivery amount.

```
=link_to 'Update delivery', store_orders_delivery_path(?????),
 method: 'POST', remote: :true
```

The form has a 'location' field

```
= f.select :location, ["country1","country2","country3"]
```

How can I send the selected location as a parameter in my link_to ?

Comment: Where is the form? Outside of `link_to`?

Comment: the form is on 'orders#new', I'm not sure what you mean by outside of link_to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand your question is:

You have a form, which do some stuff when submitted. Inside this form you want to have a link, which would send just one field from this form to another action and get some js in response updating the form.

If so, the correct way to do this would be to send an ajax request when selected location is changed. No need for link then and you would create much nicer user experience. From the event handler you can easily access the selected value and send it along with a request.

UPDATE:

In short, things I would do:

1. Get rid of this link.
2. Using javascript (CoffeScript recommended) create an event handler for this select field (jQuery: `$('#<modelname>_location').change(function() {handler here})`)
3. Inside the handler, get the value from the field (`selected_value = $(this).find('option:selected').val()`) (or value() at the end, always got those two messed up)
4. Send ajax request through js together with selected_value. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This is not a lot of code to write, but should do what you want + it will save user one click (which he might not realize is needed, get confused etc.)

Comment: you have the jist of it, but I don't understand your answer, the link_to I have is an ajax request. Do you mean submit the form via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

It should already be available in your controller, as:

```
params[:location]
```

Comment: no, I'm calling a different action, params would be available if I submitted the form, which I'm not

Comment: strange, I thought that shouldn't matter

Answer (score -1):

`= f.select :location, options_for_select(["country1","country2","country3"]), params[:location]`

Comment: I'm asking how to send the params in a link_to

Comment: when you submit the form, :location will be a parameter. this will result to a url that looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/foo/store_orders_delivery?location=0` as long as the `f.select` is within the the form `:location` value will be a param in the resultant url when you submit

Comment: I am not submitting the form